# EmberJS Routing: create child route from parent

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I am trying to create a route to add a child entity on a parent. My router looks something like this. I have a nested route in the parent's show, which I'm pretty sure is wrong. Doing this seems to stop the URL changing between page transition, and when I navigate to the addChild route from the parent's template through the `{{action doAddChild href=true}}`, the :parent_id in the URL is undefined. I'm guessing this is because I'm not setting the context on the action which should be the parent, but where do I get that from?

What's the best way to achieve this? I'm obviously barking up the wrong tree...

```coffeescript
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend
    enableLogging: true
    root: Ember.Route.extend
        index: Ember.Route.extend
            route: "/"
        parents: Ember.Route.extend
            route: "/parents"
            doShow: Ember.Route.transitionTo('show')
            index: Ember.Route.extend
                route: "/"
                connectOutlets: (router) ->
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet "parents"
            show: Ember.Route.extend
                route: "/:parent_id"
                doAddChild: Ember.Route.transitionTo('addChild')
                modelType: App.Parent
                connectOutlets: (router, parent) ->
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet "parent", parent
                addChild: Ember.Route.extend
                    route: "/addChild"
                    connectOutlets: (router) ->
                        router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet "addChild"
```

Comment: Isn't the action `{{action doAddChild}}` inside some parent context in your template? can you post the template/view ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is your show route. As you said it doesn't transition, this is because the router can only transition properly to leaf nodes. The current answer is to add a dummy index route.

```coffeescript
Router = Ember.Router.extend
    enableLogging: true
    root: Ember.Route.extend
        index: Ember.Route.extend
            route: "/"
        parents: Ember.Route.extend
            route: "/parents"
            doShow: Ember.Route.transitionTo('show.index')
            index: Ember.Route.extend
                route: "/"
                connectOutlets: (router) ->
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet "parents"
            show: Ember.Route.extend
                route: "/:parent_id"
                doAddChild: Ember.Route.transitionTo('addChild')
                connectOutlets: (router, parent) ->
                    router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet "parent", parent
                index: Ember.Route.extend
                    route: "/"
                addChild: Ember.Route.extend
                    route: "/addChild"
                    connectOutlets: (router) ->
                        router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet "addChild"
```

Fingers crossed that fixes everything else as well.